# Unnecessary Error Message Being Displayed

Tags: php, mysql, html

I've set up a form to update my blog and it was working fine up until about this morning. It keeps on turning up with an Invalid Entry ID error on the edit post page when I click the update button despite the fact that it updates the homepage.
All help is seriously appreciated.

```
 <html>

    <head>
    <title>Ultan's Blog | New Post</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/editpost.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="new-form">
    <div class="header">
</div>
<div class="form-bg">
<?php
mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root', 'root') ;
mysql_select_db ('tmlblog');

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

    $id = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['id']));
    $month = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['month']));
    $date = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['date']));
    $year = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['year']));
    $time = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['time']));
    $entry = $_POST['entry'];
    $title = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['title']));
    if (isset($_POST['password'])) $password = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['password']));
    else $password = "";

    $entry = nl2br($entry);

    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $title = addslashes($title);
        $entry = addslashes($entry);
    }

    $timestamp = strtotime ($month . " " . $date . " " . $year . " " . $time);

    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE php_blog SET timestamp='$timestamp', title='$title', entry='$entry', password='$password' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1") or print ("Can't update entry.<br />" . mysql_error());

    header("Location: post.php?id=" . $id);

}

if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $id = (int)$_POST['id'];
    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM php_blog WHERE id='$id'") or print ("Can't delete entry.<br />" . mysql_error());
    if ($result != false) {
        print "The entry has been successfully deleted from the database.";
        exit;
    }
}

if (!isset($_GET['id']) || empty($_GET['id']) || !is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    die("Invalid entry ID.");
}
else {
    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
}

$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM php_blog WHERE id='$id'") or print ("Can't select entry.<br />" . $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $old_timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
    $old_title = stripslashes($row['title']);
    $old_entry = stripslashes($row['entry']);
    $old_password = $row['password'];

    $old_title = str_replace('"','\'',$old_title);
    $old_entry = str_replace('<br />', '', $old_entry);

    $old_month = date("F",$old_timestamp);
    $old_date = date("d",$old_timestamp);
    $old_year = date("Y",$old_timestamp);
    $old_time = date("H:i",$old_timestamp);
}
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

<p><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />

<strong><label for="month">Date (month, day, year):</label></strong> 

<select name="month" id="month">
<option value="<?php echo $old_month; ?>"><?php echo $old_month; ?></option>

<option value="January">January</option>
<option value="February">February</option>
<option value="March">March</option>
<option value="April">April</option>

<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="June">June</option>
<option value="July">July</option>
<option value="August">August</option>

<option value="September">September</option>
<option value="October">October</option>
<option value="November">November</option>
<option value="December">December</option>

</select>

<input type="text" name="date" id="date" size="2" value="<?php echo $old_date; ?>" />

<select name="year" id="year">
<option value="<?php echo $old_year; ?>"><?php echo $old_year; ?></option>
<option value="2004">2004</option>

<option value="2005">2005</option>
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>

<option value="2009">2009</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
</select>

<strong><label for="time">Time:</label></strong> <input type="text" name="time" id="time" size="5" value="<?php echo $old_time; ?>" /></p>

<p><strong><label for="title">Title:</label></strong> <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="<?php echo $old_title; ?>" size="40" /> </p>

<p><strong><label for="password">Password protect?</label></strong> <input type="checkbox" name="password" id="password" value="1"<?php if($old_password == 1) echo " checked=\"checked\""; ?> /></p>

<p><textarea cols="80" rows="20" name="entry" id="entry"><?php echo $old_entry; ?></textarea></p>

<p><input type="submit" name="update" id="update" value="Update"></p>

</form>

<p><strong>Be absolutely sure that this is the post that you wish to remove from the blog!</strong><br />
</p>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="delete" id="delete" value="Delete" />

</form>
</div>
</div>
 </div>
 <div class="bottom"></div>  
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you use either `$_GET['id']` or `$_POST['id']` to identify the entry ID. So you must check on the two when you set the `$id` variable:

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['id']) || !is_numeric($_REQUEST['id']))
    die("Invalid entry ID.");
```

Or, more selectively:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
else if (isset($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['id']))
    $id = intval($_POST['id']);
else
    die('Invalid entry ID.');
```

The `empty` check is redundant to `is_numeric`: an empty string is not numeric. Also, `empty` returns `true` with `0`, which, I believe, should not halt your system since `0` could be a valid ID.

Comment: That fixed the matter of it displaying the incorrect message. Thanks for the help! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is the mixing of **POST** and **GET**

Your form uses the **POST** method:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

So you need to change:

```
if (!isset($_GET['id']) || empty($_GET['id']) || !is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    die("Invalid entry ID.");
}
else {
   $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
}
```

to:

```
    if (!isset($_POST['id']) || empty($_POST['id']) || !is_numeric($_POST['id'])) {
        die("Invalid entry ID.");
    }
   else {
    $id = (int)$_POST['id'];
   }
```

Comment: Now it won't even load the form to edit the post. Any other possible solutions?